# Transferutility in Aws sdk

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, memory-leaks

I am facing problems in uploading files to amazon s3. To track the uploading file status I am using TransferListener in addition to transferUtility. Exact problem is onProgressChanged method is not at all getting called sometimes. And sometimes it is working fine. I observed that the problem is occurring when I am trying to upload larger files. So here is how I have tried.

Code:

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        Log.d("ID VALUE",String.valueOf(this.ID));

        if(sS3Client!=null&&this.ID==-1){

            Log.d("ID","InItial setup");

            sTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(sS3Client, this.ctx);

            observer = sTransferUtility.upload(remotepath, file.getName(), file);


            observer.setTransferListener(new UploadListener(this.progressBar,observer,file.getPath()));
            observerlist.add(observer);
        }

    }
```

and UploadListener:

```
    private class UploadListener implements TransferListener{

    private ProgressBar progress;
    private TransferObserver localobserver;

    private int value;
    private String file;
    private DBoperations DB;

    private ContentValues CV;

    private ContentValues CV2;

    private UploadListener(ProgressBar progressBar,TransferObserver observer,String file){
        this.progress=progressBar;
        this.localobserver=observer;
        this.file=file;
        DB = new DBoperations(getContext());
    }
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(int i, TransferState transferState) {


        switch (transferState.toString()) {
            case "IN_PROGRESS":
            {
                CV = new ContentValues();
                CV2= new ContentValues();

                Log.d("FILE UPLOAD","IN_PROGRESS");
                CV.put(DBconstants.TableConstants.F_FILE_STATUS, constants.UPLOADING);

                DB.updateInformation(DB, DBconstants.TableConstants.TABLE_FILES, CV, DBconstants.TableConstants.F_LOCAL_PATH, this.file);

                CV2.put(DBconstants.TableConstants.UPLOAD_ID, i);
                DB.updateInformation(DB, DBconstants.TableConstants.TABLE_FILES, CV2, DBconstants.TableConstants.F_LOCAL_PATH, this.file);

            }
            break;
            case "COMPLETED":
            {
                CV= new ContentValues();

                Log.d("FILE UPLOAD","COMPLETED");
                CV.put(DBconstants.TableConstants.F_FILE_STATUS, constants.UPLOADED);

                DB.updateInformation(DB, DBconstants.TableConstants.TABLE_FILES,CV, DBconstants.TableConstants.F_LOCAL_PATH,this.file);


            }
            break;

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(int i, long l, long l1) {
        updator();
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setProgress(value);
        Log.d(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(value));
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int i, Exception e) {

    }
    private void updator()
    {
        value = (int) ((double) localobserver.getBytesTransferred() * 100 / localobserver
                .getBytesTotal());

    }
}
```

> How to solve this issue?
>
> What are the best practices to avoid this type of problems?

UPDATE:

Here 84 is my file ID. 0 is number of bytes transferrred.I printed this into logcat in onProgressChanged method

```
05-15 17:24:56.640 22043-6710/? D/UploadTask: multipart upload 84 in 22 parts.

05-15 17:24:56.649 22043-22043/? D/84: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version you use. There is a known bug in version 2.2.15 where socket timeout isn't correctly reported. Please upgrade to v2.2.16. For further questions, please open an issue at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android.

Comment: I am using 2.2.15.

Comment: does upgrading to 2.2.16 fix my issue?

Comment: In theory yes. Otherwise please open a new issue on Github.

Comment: Actually, I am facing this issue since the release of 2.2.13 release. when I upgrade to new version it works fine for few days and later issue repeats. I posted my problem in github as you said. I will use 2.2.16 and see if that works.

Comment: I am facing this issue even in new version 2.2.16. Please look at my problem.

Comment: There are more states than in_progress and completed. In case of network issue, it may become waiting_for_network. At minimum, you need a default block to figure out state changes.

Comment: I tried to print transferstate in Log, everytime the state while uploading is IN_PROGRESS and onprogressChanged never called for big files.

Comment: when i try to upload more than 3MB file,facing this problem.. small size files are uploading great. I mean files in the size of Kilobytes

Comment: Do you log errors? Is there a reliable way to reproduce it?

Comment: No errors in Log. when I chose big files to upload it is stuck at IN_PROGRESS and onProgressChnged never getting called

Comment: I can PM you my whole code in aws forum if you want to check and reproduce and see the problem

Comment: What exactly happening Is. whenever a file selected to upload onProgressChanged is getting called first time and bytes transferrred showing 0. and then it stucks there itself. I UPDATED Logcat. please check

Comment: Would you please add more log statements? I am curious about what happened in three callbacks. I suggest you try the sample on Github https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples.

Comment: Now I found this is what happening actually. It is taking much time to upload from 0 bytes to 1 bytes for lager files. I thought it was stucking there at 0. I don't know why it is happening. But once uploading started . it is going fine. Thanks for the sample. Will you please tell me why it is taking much time initially to start uploading larger files?

Comment: You can improve initial connection speed by choosing an S3 region that is closest to you. Recently launched S3 acceleration helps too, but it's not yet supported by the AWS Android SDK. Another factor is network quality.

Comment: I solved issue it is working fine now. However I have a doubt. I get temperory access key and secret key using CognitoCachingcredentialsprovider class as apart of developer authenticated identities. how to set the expiration for these temperory credentials? I am setting expiration time for token in getopenIdTokenforDeveloperIdentity class but how to set for these temperory credentials?

Comment: The default expiration is set to 1 hour. If you have other questions, please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, we don’t have the resuming feature for the large file upload using AWS SDK, however, you can try fragmenting the large files to multiple parts with smaller sizes and upload them one by one and re-assemble them once they are in S3. Saying this I would like to point you to our ***latest version of SDK 2.4.2*** which has some new updated feature. Please try configuring Transfer Utility using the newer version of SDK